# LESS: Complicated mixin parameters

Tags: less

The problem: I want to create a LESS mixin for 'notched' corners for boxes that have padding.

Image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBcKo.png

This box has its top right and bottom left corners notched out, with :before/:after content squares.

I want to create a mixin, so I don't have to make a class for every possibility of options.

Something like .boxed-corners(top right, bottom left);

My feeble attempt was this:

```
@box-padding: 10px;

.boxed-corners(@pos1 @pos2, @pos3 @pos4) {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        .bg-body();
        width: @box-padding;
        height: @box-padding;
        @pos1: 0;
        @pos2: 0;
    }
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        .bg-body();
        width: @box-padding;
        height: @box-padding;
        @pos3: 0;
        @pos4: 0;
    }
}
```

But that is invalid because between the sets of vars. Even when added, @pos1 or @pos2 won't use the string you've inputted (top, left, right, bottom).

I know I'm way off, but there's probably a way to accomplish this. Any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks seven-phases-max, that's what I was looking for:

Thank you! That was it, I just didn't know what to search for. My working code is now:

```
.boxed-corners(@pos1; @pos2; @pos3; @pos4) {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        .bg-body();
        width: @box-padding;
        height: @box-padding;
        @{pos1}: 0;
        @{pos2}: 0;
    }
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        .bg-body();
        width: @box-padding;
        height: @box-padding;
        @{pos3}: 0;
        @{pos4}: 0;
    }
}
```

The only bad thing is that all four values have to be separated by commas (bottom, left, top, right), instead of (bottom left, top right), but I'll take it.

Comment: Just look at the `@pos1: 0;` statement once more. Yes, it actually just defines new `@pos1` variable so it obviously can't be used for CSS property generation. What you need is [Property Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties).

Comment: You can use `(bottom left, top right)` actually. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/21011089 and the [corresponding documentation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions).

Comment: @bmac please don't edit your question with the answer, but create an answer yourself and accept that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that the comments of @seven-phases-max are intend to show you that creating a mixin which can be called with `(bottom left, top right)` Can be easily done levaraging the Less list functions. And indeed the corresponding documentation can be found at http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions

For instance rewrite your mixins as follows:

```
.boxed-corners(@before; @after; @box-padding:10px) {
    position: relative;
    @pos1: extract(@before,1);
    @pos2: extract(@before,2);
    @pos3: extract(@after,1);
    @pos4: extract(@after,2);

    &:before, &:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        .bg-body();
        width: @box-padding;
        height: @box-padding;
        @{pos1}: 0;
        @{pos2}: 0;
    }
    &:before {
        @{pos1}: 0;
        @{pos2}: 0;
    }
    &:after {
        @{pos3}: 0;
        @{pos4}: 0;
    }
}
```

The `.boxed-corners()` can be called as follow, all examples give the same result:

```
sel1 {
.boxed-corners(top right, bottom left);
}

sel2 {
.boxed-corners(top right; bottom left);
}

sel3 {
.boxed-corners(top, right; bottom, left);
}
```