# Passing an array into a less mixin (inline)

Tags: less, mixins

Is there a way to pass an array to a mixin as parameter?
Something like this:

```
.myMixin(@color, @array){
  ...
}

.myMixin('red',['one','two','three']);
```

The only way I could pass an array was when calling myMixin as following:

```
@array: one, two, three;
.myMixin('red',@array);
```

this mixin needs to be called many times - I don't want to set the @array variable for each call, but to pass it straight to the mixin as parameter.
Is it possible?

Comment: see [docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010520. I.e. `.myMixin(red, one two three);` or `.myMixin(red; one, two, three);` (and yes, don't use quotes, totally redundant in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @seven-phases-max, your answer was very helpful:

> see docs and stackoverflow.com/questions/21010520. I.e. .myMixin(red,
>   one two three); or .myMixin(red; one, two, three); (and yes, don't use
>   quotes, totally redundant in this case). – seven-phases-max