# Semantic-UI text colors method

Tags: css, less, semantic-ui

Semantic-UI doesn't have a good method for colouring text.

Maybe we can use this code here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1885#issuecomment-226047499:

```
@text-colors: blue, green, orange, pink, purple, red, teal, yellow, black, grey, white;
.text {
    .-(@i: length(@text-colors)) when (@i > 0) {
        @c: extract(@text-colors, @i);
        &.@{c} { color: @@c }
        .-((@i - 1));
    }.-;
}
```

I really did not even understand it until today because we can not have the text colors.

This code generates this:

```
.text.white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.text.grey {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
.text.black {
  color: #1B1C1D;
}
.text.yellow {
  color: #F2C61F;
}
...
```

Is this a good method?

What if we make something like this:

`<span class="red"></span>`

just `red` without `text`?

with this code instead:

```
@text-colors: blue, green, orange, pink, purple, red, teal, yellow, black, grey, white;
.-(@i: length(@text-colors)) when (@i > 0) {
  @c: extract(@text-colors, @i);
    &.@{c} { color: @@c }
      .-((@i - 1));
}.-;
```

**The question is for Semantic-UI experts!**

Comment: Just remove `.text` bllock from the code (What have you tried so far? The Q looks like you're asking us to write code for your. And btw., I don't think you should put copyright sticker on any trivial hello-world-like code (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954762), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789))).

Comment: Duplicate of [Loop through array of variable names in Less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-variable-names-in-less)