# Multidimensional array in Less

Tags: css, less

I'm new at Less. I want to create multidimensional array in Less.

Let me show!

```
@colors: {
@sidebar: {
    color: #FFF;
}

@content: {
    border-color: #000;
}

...
}
```

Is it possible? If i can create it like above, how can i use them?

Thanks!

Comment: *how can i use them?* - this depends solely on how *you want* to use them. First of all there's difference between [an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954762/arrays-with-less/34867089#34867089) and [a map](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature) (it's possible to use one as another but in Less it's not always transparent conversion between them), but yes you can create a multidimansional arrays and maps (or whatever combination of these structures).

Comment: An online Less-compiler - for example http://lesscss.org/less-preview/ is usually a good start to learn languages basics.

Comment: Here's a related article about someone using maps in SASS, which could be translated into Less, that you might find helpful: https://www.viget.com/articles/maps-math-and-magic-build-a-flexible-variable-system-in-sass/ (no affiliation)

Comment: @sean perfect! Thanx a lot !